# Событие вставки текста

Tags: javascript

Добрый день! не могу сообразить как перехватить текстовые данные (в частности ссылку) которые пользователь вставляет на страницу по нажатию ctrl+v?

Вставка не должна производится в выделенное инпут поле, а должна срабатывать в любом месте на странице.

Обработать само событие вставки труда не составляет,

```
$(document).bind('paste', function(e) {
     ...
});
```

а получить данные которые вставил не могу :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/uqx7L/)**

```
$('body').on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    alert(text);
});
```

Проверил в Opera 19, Yandex Browser и IE 7. Работает нормально.
В последней версии Firefox не завелось.
*p.s. фокус на сайте (первый клик) все равно нужен.*

Comment: надо не так, всё намного сложнее, если нужен именно paste, то надо делать с `setTimeout(обработчик,0);`  а вообще, есть событие input

Comment: вот он "getData('text/plain')" недостающий кусочек моей мозаики. Спасибо!
с FF решаю проблему через contenteditable="true", может и не самый красивый способ, но вариантов не нашел.